# Difference between declaring multiple classes or single class for columns in bootstrap framework

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

What is the difference in between below two methods?

Method #1

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
</div>
```

Method #2

```
  <div class="col-md-12">
    </div>
```

I'm using the second method and it works for all small and large devices perfectly then when do i need the first method?

Comment: how you are checking both method by resizing browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good question. I see a few others have answered it already, but I'd like to go a little bit more in depth in case you're curious.

In method 2, you're specifically saying "I want this container to take up the full 12 at 970px and above. Since it's a full 12, though, it will retain the full-width 12 all the way down to the smallest resolution. If, however, you had two `col-md-6`'s, the 6's would become 12's when the screen goes below 970px due to the use of md.

In your first method, you're explicitly stating that you want the column to be the full 100% at all the breakpoints.

To answer your question "Why do I need the first method?", you simply don't. The first method is overkill since bootstrap will make them all 100% by default anyways. The only reason you would want to use something like the first method is if you want to show the content in different layouts at different resolutions.

For example:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
</div>
```

This would make the column a 3 at all resolutions 992px and above (because of the md). By default, bootstrap would make the column a full 12 below 992px using the `col-md-3` class but with the declaration of `col-sm-6`, you're overwriting it and making it a 6 on all resolutions between 768px and 992px. Everthing below 768px (`col-xs-*`) would still make the column a full 12. You could overwrite this by declaring a 'col-xs-*' class just as you did with the 'col-sm-6'

If a smaller resolution is not explicitly stated, it's going to be a 12. Anything you declare will apply to that resolution and above with the exception of the xs. xs will declare 768px and below.

Here is the official bootstrap documentation to show the grid options and their associated resolutions:
https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Here's a bootply to help visualize this:
http://www.bootply.com/c0KgRryXcl

I hope that helps!

Comment: Awesome! You are great. I got your points and that was I looking for. Thank very much!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You won't notice a difference with `col-md-12` as it's the full width of the container, but if you had 2 col-md-6's, they would look squished together on a small device, hence why you'd use col-xs-12, then the breakpoint would kick in and it would change from 50% to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

The first method is useful if you want to change your proportions of divs when on a smaller device.

For example, you may have the following

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    </div>
</div>
```

So on a small device, instead of each occupy half of the width (which will be small), the two columns will be stacking up

Comment: For this example, you could actually leave the col-xs-12 out since it's going to go to a col-xs-12 by default. Declaring the col-md-6 will make the columns 100% at 992px and above. Anything below that (including the col-xs-12) will be 100%. Therefore, the col-xs-12 is already going to happen and can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

These classes are used for different devices resolution. your first method includes all devices like mobile , laptops, desktops and larger and second method includes only desktop.

Answer (score 0):

This are grid classes in bootstrap,

```
xs (for phones)
sm (for tablets)
md (for desktops)
lg (for larger desktops)
```

The classes above can be combined to create more dynamic and flexible layouts.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
</div>
```

Bootstrap's grid system allows up to 12 columns across the page.
but 12 columns each row. Your code have added 60 columns in one row its wrong.

**Basic Structure of bootstrap grid:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-*-*"></div>
  <div class="col-*-*"></div>
  <div class="col-*-*"></div>
</div>
```